# How do I change the order of integration for this integral?

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, probability-distributions, order-of-integration

The question is related to Buffon's needle experiment: **I was wondering how to change the order of integration.** The integral is shown below. Apologies if I have left out lots of stuff, I'm quite new to this level of mathematics.

$$\int_{\theta=0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \int_{b=0}^{\frac{l}{2} \cdot \sin (\theta)} \frac{4}{\pi d} \cdot d b \cdot d \theta=\frac{2 \cdot l}{\pi \cdot d}$$

Comment: Is there a reason you want to? Also you might clarify what $l$ is.

Comment: Start with a plot of the given region: it's the area bounded by the (vertical) lines $\theta=0$ and $\theta=\frac\pi2$, and by the (horizontal) line $b=0$ below and the curve $b=\frac12\sin(\theta)$ above. How would you describe this region if you make $\theta$ depend on $b$?

Comment: But why change?